# Mistake in Dry running of finding subsets question in cpp

Tags: c++, recursion, subset

## code for finding subsets

```
# include <iostream>
# include <vector>
using namespace std;
void solve(vector<int>nums, vector<int> output, int index, vector<vector<int>>& ans){
    // base case
    if(index>=nums.size()){
        ans.push_back(output);
        return ;
    }
    // exclude
    solve(nums,output,index+1,ans);
    // include
    int element=nums[index];
    output.push_back(element);
    solve(nums,output,index+1, ans);
}


# code
vector<vector<int> > Subsets(vector<int>& nums){
   vector<vector<int>> ans;
   vector<int> output;
   int index=0;
   solve(nums, output, index, ans);
   return ans;
}
int main(){
   int n,a;
    cin>>n;

    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    vector<int> num;
    cout<<"Enter the elements in nums : ";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
     cin>>a;
      num.push_back(a);
    }
   ans=Subsets(num);
   cout<<" ans vector : ";
      cout<<"[";
   for(int i=0; i<ans.size(); i++){
        cout<<"[";
      for(int j=0; j<ans[i].size(); j++){
      cout<< ans[i][j]<<" ";
      }
cout<<"],"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"]"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#output

```
3
Enter the elements in nums : 1 2 3
 ans vector : [[],
[3 ],
[2 ],
[2 3 ],
[1 ],
[1 3 ],
[1 2 ],
[1 2 3 ],
]
```

## doubt :

above code is giving the correct output but i am having problem in dry running part. since we passing ans and output vectors in the function argument it will retain the content from below recursive function calls which causes the duplicacy of elements(2) as shown during 8th function call. what am i doing wrong in dry running part?[image]

tried to dryrun but getting dplicacy of elements

Comment: Your notes are unreadable, but I suspect that what you're missing is that `output` is passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: Apart from `output` not being passed by reference you absolutely should pass `nums` by reference as well (`const` this time as you do not modify) – otherwise you create yet another copy of with every recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

The `output` parameter is passed by value, not by reference. This results in a copy being created. The local `output` variable in the "original" `solve` call remains untouched.

The parameter for the calls should therefore be

Call A

```
solve({1, 2, 3}, {}, 0, ...)
```

which calls

```
solve({1, 2, 3}, {}, 0, ...)
```

... a few more recursive calls ...

Now for call A the local `output` variable has not changes, since the called function received a different object(a copy).

Then 1 is added to the output vector, a copy is made and passed to the second recursive call for call A.

```
solve({1, 2, 3}, {1}, 0, ...)
```

---

Note: Since `nums` is the same for all calls, but a copy may be expensive, it would be preferred to pass it by reference to const. Applying `const` to the object will have the compiler enforce that your code does not modify (= use non-const member functions/operators) the vector:

```
void solve(vector<int> const& nums, vector<int> output, int index, vector<vector<int>>& ans) ...
```